# Haskell: function signature

Tags: haskell, types

This program compiles without problems:

```
bar :: MonadIO m
    => m String
bar = undefined

run2IO :: MonadIO m
       => m String
       -> m String
run2IO foo  = liftIO bar
```

When I change `bar` to `foo` (argument name),

```
run2IO :: MonadIO m
       => m String
       -> m String
run2IO foo  = liftIO foo
```

I get:

> Couldn't match type ‘m’ with ‘IO’
>         ‘m’ is a rigid type variable bound by
>             the type signature for run2IO :: MonadIO m => m String -> m String
>   ...
>
> Expected type: IO String
>   Actual type: m String ...

Why are the 2 cases are not equivalent?

Answer (score 9):

Remember the type of `liftIO`:

```
liftIO :: MonadIO m => IO a -> m a
```

Importantly, the first argument must be a concrete `IO` value. That means when you have an expression `liftIO x`, then `x` must be of type `IO a`.

When a Haskell function is universally quantified (using an implicit or explicit `forall`), then that means the *function caller* chooses what the type variable is replaced by. As an example, consider the `id` function: it has type `a -> a`, but when you evaluate the expression `id True`, then `id` takes the type `Bool -> Bool` because `a` is instantiated as the `Bool` type.

Now, consider your first example again:

```
run2IO :: MonadIO m => m Integer -> m Integer
run2IO foo = liftIO bar
```

The `foo` argument is completely irrelevant here, so all that actually matters is the `liftIO bar` expression. Since `liftIO` *requires* its first argument to be of type `IO a`, then `bar` *must* be of type `IO a`. However, `bar` is polymorphic: it actually has type `MonadIO m => m Integer`.

Fortunately, `IO` has a `MonadIO` instance, so the `bar` value is *instantiated* using `IO` to become `IO Integer`, which is okay, because `bar` is universally quantified, so its instantiation is chosen by its use.

Now, consider the other situation, in which `liftIO foo` is used, instead. This *seems* like it’s the same, but it actually isn’t at all: this time, the `MonadIO m => m Integer` value is an argument to the function, not a separate value. The quantification is over the entire function, not the individual value. To understand this more intuitively, it might be helpful to consider `id` again, but this time, consider its definition:

```
id :: a -> a
id x = x
```

In this case, `x` cannot be instantiated to be `Bool` within its definition, since that would mean `id` could only work on `Bool` values, which is obviously wrong. Effectively, within the implementation of `id`, `x` must be used completely generically—it cannot be instantiated to a specific type because that would violate the parametricity guarantees.

Therefore, in your `run2IO` function, `foo` must be used completely generically as an arbitrary `MonadIO` value, not a specific `MonadIO` instance. The `liftIO` call attempts to use the specific `IO` instance, which is disallowed, since the caller might not provide an `IO` value.

---

It is possible, of course, that you might want the argument to the function to be quantified in the same way as `bar` is; that is, you might want its instantiation to be chosen by the implementation, not the caller. In that case, you can use the `RankNTypes` language extension to specify a different type using an explicit `forall`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

run3IO :: MonadIO m => (forall m1. MonadIO m1 => m1 Integer) -> m Integer
run3IO foo = liftIO foo
```

This will typecheck, but it’s not a very useful function.

Comment: It may or may not be worth mentioning the `PrimBase` class in `primitive`.

Answer (score 5):

In the first, you're using `liftIO` on `bar`. That actually requires `bar :: IO String`. Now, `IO` happens to be (trivially) an instance on `MonadIO`, so this works – the compiler simply throws away the polymorphism of `bar`.

In the second case, the compiler doesn't get to decide what particular monad to use as the type of `foo`: it's fixed by the environment, i.e. the *caller* can decide what `MonadIO` instance it should be. To again get the freedom to choose `IO` as the monad, you'd need the following signature:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types, UnicodeSyntax #-}

run2IO' :: MonadIO m
       => (∀ m' . MonadIO m' => m' String)
       -> m String
run2IO' foo  = liftIO foo
```

... however I don't think you really want that: you might then as well write

```
run2IO' :: MonadIO m => IO String -> m String
run2IO' foo  = liftIO foo
```

or simply `run2IO = liftIO`.

Comment: Can I ask where you can get information on the compiler behaviour? I've been coding in Haskell for about 6 months and would like to take a step up and learn what's happening under the hood.

Comment: Er, what do you mean by “information on the compiler behaviour”? You can certainly look at [the source code](http://git.haskell.org/ghc.git) to learn what GHC does. I actually never read much of it – I find it much more useful to just write lots of code and see what happens.

Comment: It's best not to think of learning about behaviors like this as learning the compiler since this behavior is well specified by the language itself.  The type of quantification is provided by type signatures is not an uncommon tripping point and its a good thing to dig into explicitly rather than pass over with a "hurm, someday I'll understand" sort of response.